# Where are the limits for Qt types?

Tags: c++, qt, limits, numeric-limits

Regularly, I could reference limits.h to see what the max is for a certain type, like an int or long.

In Qt, there are types like qlonglong.  Is there a header file and/or documentation that can be used in a similar way to manually or programmatically reference the limits of these types?

Comment: There's a chance the Qt types distill down to one of the basic types- have you tried calling e.g., std::numeric_limits<qlonglong>::max()?

Comment: @fbrereto: put that as an answer as this is very likely the case.

Comment: Even when they're not typedefs for standard types, it's possible and indeed intended to specialize `std::numeric_limits<T>` for numeric types.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a high likelihood the Qt types distill down to one of the basic types for which `numeric_limits` are defined. Have you tried calling e.g., `std::numeric_limits<qlonglong>::max()`?

As MSalters points out, too, if the types are not builtin `numeric_limits` can still be specialized for them. If that were the case one would hope Qt would include them.

Comment: `#include <limits>`
That will get access to `std::numeric_limits<qint64>::max()` and others.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [QtGlobal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qint8-typedef) documentation.

For some of the non-obvious ones:
**qlonglong** - 64-bit
**qptrdiff** - 32-bit or 64-bit depending on platform
**qreal** - double (float on ARM architectures)
**quintptr** - unsigned 32-bit or 64-bit depending on platform
**qulonglong** - unsigned 64-bit
**uchar**, **uint**, **ulong**, **ushort** - convenience shorthand for unsigned types

Comment: Are some of these deprecated since the header <cstdint> has become part of the standard ? Or if not deprecated, are they just specified as backward-compatible aliases ? The doc on the QtGlobal page seems very vague to me.