# What is maximum number value of quint64 in Qt?

Tags: qt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are the limits for Qt types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788693/where-are-the-limits-for-qt-types)

I need maximum number of quint64 for example we have a macro for ulong ULONG_MAX

Is there any equal macro for quint64?

Comment: I'm guessing that based on its name that it's a 64-bit type....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can find an answer in the official documentation:

`quint64` is a typedef for `unsigned long long int` (`unsigned __int64` on Windows). This type is guaranteed to be 64-bit on all platforms supported by Qt.

So, `quint64` is a 64-bit type for unsigned integers.
We can find its maximum value this way:

```
2^64-1 = 18446744073709551615
```

As it was told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788693/where-are-the-limits-for-qt-types), you can get the same result by including `#include <limits>`, and the output result of

```
std::numeric_limits<quint64>::max();
```